# GWT CellTable Set Column to HTML

Tags: html, gwt, celltable, flextable

I want to put a FlexTable into a CellTable, so in my String getValue() I created the FlexTable and returned ft.toString(), where ft is my FlexTable.

However, When I do table.addColumn(flex_table_string, "Header"), GWT does not render the HTML but rather leaves it as text

Please Help,

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build a `Cell` that constructs the HTML table using the `SafeHtmlBuilder` rather than building a widget and getting its HTML representation (BTW, you shouldn't even use `toString()` to do that, but rather create, say, a `SimplePanel`, put the widget in it and then call `getElement().getInnerHTML()` on the parent panel).
There are two main reasons:

- `SafeHtmlBuilder` will be faster (that's the whole point of `CellTable` vs. `Grid` or `FlexTable`)
- you're breaking expectations: *serializing* a widget will lose all event handling.

---

That being said, what you're asking is indeed possible: use a `Cell` that uses the `SafeHtmlBuilder`'s `appendHtmlConstant` method. Either make one, or, unlike the escape/unescape roundtrip suggested by Alex, use a `TextCell` but construct it with a custom `SafeHtmlRenderer` (extend `AbstractSafehtmlRenderer` for simplicity) that uses `SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace all the `&lt;` and `&gt;` with < and >.

```
protected void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    String html = value.asString().replaceAll("&lt;", "<").replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
    sb.appendHtmlConstant(html);
}
```